# MVC, Entity Framework Select data from multiple models

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

In a ASP.NET MVC3 Razor project I have 2 Models

```
public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Contents { get; set; }
        public int Author { get; set; }
    }

 public class Author
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

*`Post.Author` field links to `Author.Id` field*

In a view, I need to display list of

```
Post.Title
Post.Contents
Author.Name
```

How to display the information joining (from) both models?

***Note :** I guess I need to use a `ViewModel` and bind the view with `IEnumerable` List, but I have no idea how to select the data from both models*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a viewmodel which will have ONLY properties which u want to be displayed on view

```
public class PostViewModel
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Contents { get; set; }
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }

}
```

You populate this viewmodel with your data in your controller action taking necessary joins

```
public ActionResult GetAuthorInfor()
{
   var query = //context.Post join with context.Author
               Select new  PostViewModel()
               {
                  Id = post.id,
                  Title = post.title,
                  Contents = post.contents,
                  AuthorName = author.authorname
               }
   return view(query.Single());
}
```

and create a typed view to render this model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... Its working. (Had to Change query.Single() to query.ToList())

Answer (score 1):

Model **Post.cs**:

```
public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Contents { get; set; }
        public int AuthorID { get; set; }

        public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
    }
```

Model **Author.cs** :

```
public class Author
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
```

**DBContext** Class:

```
public class SampleDB : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Author> Authors{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts{ get; set; }
    }
```

*I.Way(using direkt view)*

you can use on View like this :

```
 Samp.Models.SampleDB dbPosts = new Samp.Models.SampleDB();
 foreach (var post in dbPosts.Posts.ToList())
 {
   string post_Title = post.title;
   string post_Contents = post.Contents;
   string author_Name = post.Author.Name;
 }
```

*II.Way (Using via Controller) -Recommended-*

you can use on Controller like this :

```
Samp.Models.SampleDB db = new Samp.Models.SampleDB();

 public ActionResult Index()
 {
   return View(db.Posts.ToList());
 }
```

Using this on **View**:

```
@model IEnumerable<Samp.Models.Post>


foreach (var post in Model.Posts.ToList())
     {
       string post_Title = post.title;
       string post_Contents = post.Contents;
       string author_Name = post.Author.Name;
     }
```